# How do I properly handle rotation of a UIScrollView containing UIImageViews?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, orientation-changes

I'm developing an image viewer, much like the Photos App.

It's a UIScrollView with paging enabled with images loaded from the internet, so I've adapted portions of the [LazyTableImages sample](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html). The Scroll View and each ImageView inside of it have all of their autoresize mask flags set.

When I first observed how resizes were happening during rotation, it looked good, but once I started trying to interact with the scroll view, I realized that I also had to programmatically change the size of the contentView. I did that by implementing didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: in my view controller.

```
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(numberOfImages * portraitWidth, [scrollView bounds].size.height)];
```

With interaction behaving properly, I then discovered that, if I was viewing the second photo and rotated, portions of both the 1st and 2nd photos would be shown on the screen. I needed to change the contentOffset as well.

I've tried to fix this two ways - both by using the scrollRectToVisible:animated: method of UIScrollView, as well as trying to set the contentOffset property directly. And I've experimented by putting this code in implementations of both the "one-step" and "two-step" responses to changes in Orientation. For example:

```
-(void)didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(currentlyViewedPhotoIndex * largeImageHeight,0) animated:YES];
```

In all cases though, it just looks janky as hell. Either I clearly see the scroll happen, or it just jumps. Uuuuuuuuuuugly! Is there a way to do this so that it behaves exactly like the Photos app does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I wound up doing instead - just before rotation starts, hide the UIScrollView and create a UIImageView that contains the currently viewed image. Rotate, that image will rotate all nice and pretty, and when rotation completes remove the ImageView and unhide the Scroll View.

Update - if you're reading this today (anytime after iOS 6), use a UIPageViewController and set transitionStyle to UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll, for crissakes.

Answer (score 1):

I did something slightly different when faced with the same problem. In `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, I hide all of the UIScrollView's subviews except for the currently displayed subview, and in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` I unhide the subviews.